# On Mac OS X Snow Leopard, is there a way to setup a different mouse tracking speed depending on the mouse that is connected?

Tags: mac, mouse

With my laptop, I use a Magic Mouse at work and a Logitech mouse at home. With the same "tracking speed" configuration on the Preferences, the Logitech moves much faster, which forces me to change the tracking speed every time I switch between the Magic Mouse and the Logitech mouse.

Is there a way to setup a different "tracking speed" depending on the mouse that is connected, maybe through a third-party utility that works with Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem to support the Magic Mouse yet, but it should soon.

http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html

Comment: Interesting; I didn't know about this alternative to the standard drivers. Like you said, this is not a solution yet, for the I'll definitely keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 2):

I dont' have OSX myself, but this [little application](http://triq.net/software/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x)  might be able to help you.

[This page](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20051224140406391) goes down into the neaty gritty of the configuration files that control the tracking speed of a mouse.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: @Chris, thank you for the response. I am aware of this tool, but as stated on the page, unfortunately it doesn't work on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2):

ControllerMate at http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/ will do this. You can assign a custom acceleration curve to each mouse you connect. Plus do a whole lot of other things. It's a total steal at $15.

Comment: It is not clear to me if ControllerMate can be used for this on Snow Leopard. As mentioned on http://triq.net/software/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x, "Apple dropped the mouse acceleration API" so this may affect ControllerMate as well. (Or it may not affect ControllerMate; again, this is not clear to me.)

Comment: Looks like it's $24.95 now.